# Why do bitwise operation (and, or, xor) on floating-point data types exist in SSE/AVX

Tags: sse

SSE has `_mm_xor_ps`, `_mm_xor_pd`, `_mm_and_ps`, `_mm_and_pd`, `_mm_or_ps`, `_mm_or_pd`.

As floating-point type consist of mantissa, exponent, and sign, the result of treating them as sequence of bits does not look meaningful (except xoring with self to have zero, but for this we have `_mm_setzero_ps()`/`pd`/`si128`).

If the purpose is still working as sequence of bits, then `ps`/`pd` distinction is not relevant, and integer versions look more appropriate: `_mm_and_si128`, `_mm_xor_si128`, `_mm_or_si128`

So what's the use case for these operations?

Comment: (I got here from the home page, I don't know anything about the subject matter) what does it matter if the bitwise operations are "labelled" as "floating point". They still apply to all the bits, right? So shouldnt it work just the same on any bits, whether you use them to represent Floats or not? In other words, if "integer bitwise ops" did exist, how would they be any different from the floating point ones?

Comment: SSE1 (`_ps`) came first, and we of course wanted sign flip / clear / copy on `float` aka `ps` vectors before SSE2 existed.  You're right that the `pd` versions are useless wastes of opcode coding space, perhaps only existing for encoding consistency and regularity, and/or decoder transistor complexity, as discussed recently.  ([Why does clang emit the 32bit version of an instruction to compute the absolute of a 64bit value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69095826)).  Perhaps you can reformulate your question in light of that?

Comment: And/or so it's not a simple duplicate of [What's the difference between logical SSE intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233017) about performance differences (back-end ports, and SIMD-int vs. float domains for bypass-forwarding delays.)

Comment: Also, since you're asking about *intrinsics*, not asm instructions, you should be using `_mm_setzero_ps()`, not `_mm_xor_ps(v,v)`, if you want a zeroing idiom.

Comment: @Alexander: All of the intrinsic functions (and the corresponding asm instructions) actually *do* exist, and yes they are architecturally equivalent, differing only in performance (and code size for non-`ps`).  And of course Pentium-III can only run the `ps` versions because it doesn't have SSE2, only SSE.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm fine with duplicate resolution, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62111946/2945027 is what I was asking, and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/69095326/2945027 is what I didn't ask, but was curios about