# How to initialize experimental/simd vector?

Tags: c++, simd, aggregate-initialization

This page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/simd shows only these two initialization methods of a SIMD vector:

1. All elements to the same value: `native_simd<int> a = 1`
2. Using a lambda: `fixed_size_simd<float, 8> a([](int i) {return i;});`

Is there another option? I would like this to work:

```
const fixed_size_simd<int, 4> a{3, 1, 4, 1};
```

Comment: Maybe like this `const fixed_size_simd<int, 4> a{::std::array{3, 1, 4, 1}.data(), 0};`

Comment: @user7860670 It doesn't compile. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: [How can I do efficiently bitwise majority voting on 3, 5, 7, 9 inputs with SSE/SSE2/AVX/...?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77682420) shows an example of initializing a `std::experimental::simd` vector from an array.  (Buried in a fairly complex function, see `V vr{r + c, element_aligned};` where `r` is a `uint8_t const*` and `c` is a `size_t`.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/simd/simd/simd for all the available constructors

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. In order to preserve my sanity, I will use Agner library where I can just write *Vec4i a{3, 1, 4, 1};*

Comment: @user7860670 Small modification of your solution works: `fixed_size_simd<int, 4> a{array<int, 4>{3, 1, 4, 1}.data(), element_aligned};`. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Comment: @PeterCordes There is a way to initialize it from elements https://stackoverflow.com/a/77863167/412080

Answer (score 2):

This library doesn't provide a convenient constructor from elements at the moment, it seems.

It is worth noticing, that generator [constructor #4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/simd/simd/simd) you mention receives a `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, i>` argument, which can be used to index an array, `std::tuple` or a *variadic function template* argument at compile time. `to_simd` function below does the latter:

```
#include <experimental/simd>
#include <type_traits>

namespace stdx = std::experimental;

//
// Boilerplate. C++20 Pack indexing supercedes nth_arg.
//
template<size_t N, class T0, class... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) nth_arg(T0&& a0, Ts&&... as) noexcept {
    if constexpr(N)
        return nth_arg<N - 1>(std::forward<Ts>(as)...);
    else
        return std::forward<T0>(a0);
}

template<class T0, class... Ts>
constexpr auto to_simd(T0 a0, Ts... as) noexcept {
    using V = stdx::simd<T0, stdx::simd_abi::deduce_t<T0, 1 + sizeof...(as)>>;
    auto generator = [&](auto i) { return nth_arg<i.value>(a0, as...); };
    return V{generator};
}

// 
// Unit-test to_simd return types.
// 
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(to_simd(0.)), stdx::simd<double, stdx::simd_abi::deduce_t<double, 1>>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(to_simd(0., 0.)), stdx::simd<double, stdx::simd_abi::deduce_t<double, 2>>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(to_simd(0., 0., 0., 0.)), stdx::simd<double, stdx::simd_abi::deduce_t<double, 4>>>);

//
// Usage.
//
auto f_sse(double a0, double a1) {
    auto v = to_simd(a0, a1);
    return v;
}

auto f_sse0() {
    auto v = to_simd(0., 0.);
    return v;
}

auto f_avx(double a0, double a1, double a2, double a3) {
    auto v = to_simd(a0, a1, a2, a3);
    return v;
}

auto f_avx0() {
    auto v = to_simd(0., 0., 0., 0.);
    return v;
}
```

Generated [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/KMfYcq1hM) is identical to hand-coded initialization using CPU-specific vector intrinsic functions.

Comment: Does this optimize down to a constant when these are called with constant args?  BTW, the clang behaviour isn't a bug, it's an optimization that isn't harmful for AVX and saves code-size for SSE, so it does it anyway: [Why does clang emit a 32-bit float ps instruction for the absolute value of a 64-bit double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69095326)  . (It *is* harmful for latency when it uses `vblendvps` instead of `vblendvb` on *integer* data, though.  That's a missed optimization.  And perhaps not great when it uses `vmovaps` loads on integer data, not just on double or float.  Stores are ok

Comment: @PeterCordes Zero constants result in `vxorp`. Thank you for clarifying single vs double moves.

Comment: And non-trivial constants like `(3., 1., 4., 1.)` result in a load from `.rodata`, good. (https://godbolt.org/z/qM5MfjWdq).  BTW, you forgot to turn of "execute the code", that's why your Godbolt link has errors about no main.