# Add 32-bit floats in eax/ecx registers?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, fpu, x87

I have a pair of 32-bit floats stored in eax and ecx. Can I directly load these into the FPU to operate on them, without first storing to memory? This would simplify some compiler code significantly, but `fld` seems to only be able to operate on memory.

Comment: No, you can't. As far as compiler code goes, I doubt it makes a significant difference if you have to go through memory. You can simulate `fld r32` easily enough (`push r32; fld [esp]; pop r32`). Anyway, consider using SSE if available.

Comment: @Jester I'm open to using SSE, what would the equivalent SSE code be for that push-fld-pop example?

Comment: You can move to an SSE register directly using `MOVD` instruction. You could do `movd xmm0, eax; movd xmm1, ecx; addss xmm0, xmm1;` then move back as necessary. Of course you could use xmm registers for your floats in general :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you :) If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. And yeah I guess I could use the xmm registers for everything, but I'm trying to keep the code simple even if it does generate inefficient assembly.

Comment: @Jester … but `movd` is an integer instruction, and the subsequent floating-point instruction may be penalized, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996384/do-i-get-a-performance-penalty-when-mixing-sse-integer-float-simd-instructions

Comment: @PascalCuoq that is true. But `eax` and `ecx` are integer registers, so this "reinterpretation" must be done eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that. As far as generating code goes, you can simulate `fld r32` easily enough through the following sequence for example (optimized for size ;)) :

```
push r32
fld [esp]
pop r32
```

Consider using SSE if available, which does offer direct GPR-to-XMM moves using the `movd` instruction. Adding the two registers could then look something like:

```
movd xmm0, eax
movd xmm1, ecx
addss xmm0, xmm1
```

If you need the result in a GPR, you can move it back using another `movd`.