# What's the difference between the XOR instructions "VPXORD", "VXORPS" and "VXORPD" in Intel's AVX2

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, avx, avx2, avx512

I see in AVX2 instruction set, Intel distinguishes the XOR operations of integer, double and float with different instructions. For Integer there's "VPXORD", and for double "VXORPD", for float "VXORPS"

However, per my understanding, they should all be the same XOR operation on binary data. E.g., XOR of two 256-bit registers, and has nothing to do with the actual data type. Why do we need to use different instructions for different data types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between logical SSE intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804902/whats-the-difference-between-logical-sse-intrinsics)

Comment: @Mysticial: maybe not exactly, [`vpxord/q` requires AVX512F](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pxor) for masking on 32/64-bit elements, but EVEX [`vxorps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xorps) (for zmm, or x/ymm16..31) requires AVX512DQ so surprisingly KNL doesn't have it, only "integer" vpxord/q!

Comment: Note that unless you need to pad code and want to avoid nops use `vpxor` instead of `vpxor{size}` as you save 2 bytes in the encoding. If you use the intrinsic wrapper [GCC will automatically use the short encoding](https://godbolt.org/z/MPbdKT15W)

Answer (score 2):

Here's all the SIMD xor instructions there are:

```
ENCODING                 MNEMONIC  ENCODING  EXTENSION  DOMAIN   TYPE
               0F EE /r  pxor      legacy    MMX        MMX      quad
               0F 57 /r  xorps     legacy    SSE        FP       packed single
            66 0F EE /r  pxor      legacy    SSE2       integer  double-quad
            66 0F 57 /r  xorpd     legacy    SSE2       FP       packed double
   VEX.256.0F.WIG 57 /r  vxorps    VEX       AVX        FP       packed single
VEX.256.66.0F.WIG 57 /r  vxorpd    VEX       AVX        FP       packed double
VEX.256.66.0F.WIG EE /r  vpxor     VEX       AVX2       integer  double-quad
EVEX.512.66.0F.W0 EE /r  vpxord    EVEX      AVX512F    integer  double word
EVEX.512.66.0F.W1 EE /r  vpxorq    EVEX      AVX512F    integer  quad word
   EVEX.512.0F.W0 57 /r  vxorps    EVEX      AVX512DQ   FP       packed single
EVEX.512.66.0F.W1 57 /r  vxorpd    EVEX      AVX512DQ   FP       packed double
```

(only counting those with the maximum vector size supported)

These instructions all boil down to just two opcodes: `0F EF` for `pxor` and `0F 57` for `xorps` and `xorpd`.  The key difference between these opcodes is *domain.*  `pxor` is an integer domain instruction<sup>†</sup> and `xorps`/`xorpd` are FP domain instructions.

Internally, each SIMD register is associated with (you could say “located in”) one of these two domains, depending on the last instruction that wrote to it.  If you access a register from the domain it is not currently associated with, you incur an extra cycle of latency* while the register is moved/copied to the other domain.  That's why for some instructions that are useful for both integer and FP operations, two versions exist.  One scoped for floating point and one scoped for integer.  This explains why two opcodes exist.

Now why are there different element types for `xorps` and `xorpd`?  Both are the same instruction, with the only difference being that `xorpd` takes an extra `66` prefix to indicate the double operand size.  This is a systematic thing; with FP-domain instructions, no prefix indicates packed-single, `66` indicates packed-double, `F3` indicates scalar-single and `F2` indicates scalar-double.  While scalar operation is not supported for this opcode, the CPU designers did not see a need to explicitly ban the useless distinction between single and double operation and you can use both `xorps` and `xorpd`.  There's no difference between these two with SSE and AVX.

The instruction `pxor` on the other hand is an integer domain instruction originating with MMX.  Here, no prefix indicates MMX operation and a `66` prefix indicates SSE operation.  Data size is indicated in the opcode instead of using prefixes.  For `pxor`, the nominal data size is thus quad or double-quad, meaning, a full register/lane.

With AVX, all of these instructions gained the option to be VEX encoded to support non-destructive operation (destination separate from source) and to allow 256 bit vector size.  The use of VEX encoding is represented with a leading V in the mnemonic, leading to `vpxor`, `vxorps`, and `vxorpd`.  Everything else stays the same.

With AVX-512, things changed a bit.  This new instruction set extension supports *masking* for almost all instructions.  Each element can be masked to “keep old value” or “zero out” subject to a mask register.  This requires amending SSE and AVX instructions that did not have an element size designated with element sizes, as the element size dictates how the masking is applied.  This is achieved by using the previously unused W bit of the REX/VEX/EVEX prefix to differentiate `vpxor` into `vpxord` (double word) and `vpxorq` (quad word).  Note the use of integer data types in comparison to the FP data types used for `xorps` and `xorpd`.  To make the decoding simpler, the W bit now needs to be set in accordance with element size for `vxorps` and `vxorpd`, too.

Unfortunately no variants for byte or word xor operation were added (these would have necessitated new opcodes), so if such masking is desired, a separate move/blend step has to be used.

I hope this clears up the differences.  It's really not as complicated as it looks.

---

* The precise penalty varies between microarchitectures and may not exist at all.  When in doubt, measure.

<sup>†</sup> MMX is a domain on its own and obsolete for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Incidentally, ARM64 asimd took the opposite approach: vector bitwise operations can *only* be expressed as operating on byte elements.  Which can be confusing in its own way: you may have a long block of code that operates on 64-bit elements, and all the register operands to all your instructions look like `v0.2d`, `v1.2d`, etc.  But when it comes time to do an xor, `eor v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d` is a syntax error, and you have to write `eor v0.16b, v1.16b, v2.16b`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am aware of that.  It's because the field that usually indicates element size is repurposed to distinguish between `AND`, `BIC`, `ORR`, and `ORN` instead.